# self referencing update using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, self

I wonder if there is a way to make a self referencing update in MongoDB, so you can use object's params on a $set query. Here is an example:

```
> db.labels.save({"name":"label1", "test":"hello"})
> db.labels.save({"name":"label2", "test":"hello"})
> db.labels.save({"name":"label3", "test":"hello"})
> db.labels.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f1200e2f8509434f1d28496"), "name" : "label1", "test" : "hello" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f1200e6f8509434f1d28497"), "name" : "label2", "test" : "hello" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f1200eaf8509434f1d28498"), "name" : "label3", "test" : "hello" }
```

I saw that you can use this syntax on $where queries: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand%7B%7B%24where%7D%7D

```
> db.myCollection.find( { a : { $gt: 3 } } ); 
> db.myCollection.find( { $where: "this.a > 3" } );
> db.myCollection.find("this.a > 3");
> f = function() { return this.a > 3; } db.myCollection.find(f);
```

So, I tried with:

> db.labels.update({"test":"hola"}, {$set : {"test": this.name})

but it didn't work.

The expected result is:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f1200e2f8509434f1d28496"), "name" : "label1", "test" : "label1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f1200e6f8509434f1d28497"), "name" : "label2", "test" : "label2" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f1200eaf8509434f1d28498"), "name" : "label3", "test" : "label3" }
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Update**:

It can be done by now using

```
db.labels.updateMany(
   {"test":"hola"},
   [{ $set: { test: "$name" }}],
)
```

**Old Answer**

At present there is no straight way to do that. But you can workaround this by

```
    db.labels.find({"test":"hola"}).forEach(function (doc) {
           doc.test = doc.name;
           db.labels.save(doc); 
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the response RameshVel. I'm using Mongoid, so I will loop over the results and save it with the old value. I'm worried about the performance. Any recommendation?

Comment: @fertapric, sorry nope :( . I am afraid thats the only way.

Comment: @RameshVel Is that still true for the current version of MongoDb?

Comment: @Cartesius00, seems its still a open request per https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1765?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel

Comment: Sorry but, isn't the use of "snapshot()" method needed here to prevent updating the same doc twice ? or maybe I did not understand well what the snapshot option does.

Comment: MongoDB 4.01 : "$name" is simply resolved into... "$name" ! not the value of document.name . Furthermore, the second argument, $set:, doesn't accept an array. It must be a document or an aggregation.

Answer (score 4):

### new in MongoDB 4.2

**[FYI] Below approach avoids row-by-row operations (which can cause performance issues), and shifts the processing load onto the DB itself.**

> "Starting in **MongoDB 4.2**, the db.collection.update() method can
> accept an aggregation pipeline that specifies the modifications to
> perform." [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-with-aggregation-pipeline)

The pipeline has access to each documents' fields, thus allowing self-referencial updates.
Please see the [documentation on this, which includes an example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#modify-a-field-using-the-values-of-the-other-fields-in-the-document) of this sort of update.

Following the example from the OP's question the update would be:

```
db.labels.update(
   {"test":"hello"},
   [{ $set: { test: "$name" }}],
   { multi: true }
);
```

Please note that the `$set` used in the pipeline refers to the [aggregation stage `$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/), and not the update operator `$set`.

For those familiar with the aggregate pipeline in earlier MongoDB versions: the `$set` stage is an alias for `$addFields`.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37280419/1720476