# Update MongoDB document with string value of DBRef ID in the same document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-update, dbref

I'm attempting to extract and set the string value of a `DBRef` in one of my collections.

Given the following entry,

`"thing" : DBRef("things", ObjectId("id-string-here"), "my-db")`

The desired result is to have alongside it,

`"thingString": "id-string-here"`

I've attempted to use `$set` to achieve this, but am struggling to access the nested value,

`db.myCollection.update({predicate}, {$set:{thingString:"$thing.id"}})`

But this just sets the literal string `"$thing.id"`.

Using `$thing` sets the `DBRef` itself, which defeats the whole purpose, but means that it does find the relevant field during the update.

I've attempted the following variations, but to no avail:

- `$thing._id`
- `$thing.oid`
- `$thing.$id`
- `thing.$id`
- `thing.$_id`
- `thing.$oid`

As well as wrapping the `$set` statement in array as in [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64388913/4623578), but in that case, `$thing.$id` errors out, saying `FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.`, and when `thing` is not prefixed with `$`, nothing is updated.

```
db.myCollection.updateOne({predicate}, [{$set:{stringThing: "thing.$id" }}])
```

And based on the comments,

```
db.myCollection.updateOne({predicate}, [{$set:{ stringThing: { $toString: "$thing.$id" }}}])
```

I've also attempted the same variations as above there, but in that case, nothing is updated.

Given that I can `find` using `{ "thing.$id" : ObjectId("id-string-here") }`, I assume it would be possible to also access it in `$set` somehow.

`MongoDB server version: 4.2.24`

Comment: I think the aggregation style update is indeed what you'll need here. Is something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JQPsf2SP6Xc) what you are looking for? If not, could you modify the example to show it failing in the manner that you mention?

Comment: @user20042973 added more examples. I did find a workaround using an ORM, but it would still be nice to figure this one out..

Comment: Can you add the sample _document_ that fails? The mongoplayground link seems to work okay, so trying to narrow down the problem here